# How to save an 'UPDATED DICTIONARY' in python?

Tags: python

I'm unable to save the updated dictionary in python.
I have made a simple program which takes user inputs:'username and password' as 'values and keys' and, verifies them in the dictionary, for match. (The dictionary already has 2 usernames and passwords)
so, if the username is not in the dictionary then, the program takes new vales and keys and adds the new values into the dictionary.
but, when I run the code AGAIN after the dictionary gets updated, The dictionary shows the data with initial values. (It shows the values and keys that I've put manually inside it, but not the updated ones)
please help!

THIS IS THE CODE

```
import getpass

database = {"user1": "123476", "user2": "654321"}
username = input("Enter Your Username : ")
if username not in database:
    print("This Username is not found in our database, Please create one!")
    username1 = input("Enter Username: ")
    password1 = input("Enter Password: ")
    updated = {username1 : password1}
    database |= updated
print(database)

username = input("Enter Your Username : ") 
password = getpass.getpass("Enter Your Password : ")
for i in database:
    if username == i:
        while password != database.get(i):
            password = getpass.getpass("Enter Your Password Again : ")
        break
print("Verifivation Successful.")
```

Comment: You will, of course, need to load/save the dictionary from/to some kind of storage like a file. Perhaps the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module can help.

Comment: Such data must be stored as file separately. There is e. g. the "pickle" module for this. You should work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) if not done yet.

Comment: Is there any other method? without using pickle?

Comment: There are modules for JSON, CSV, XML and as Sqlite database in the standard library. There are additional libraries for other formats or you can write code to store it in your own data format.

Comment: Yeah, but I need to make it simple. For example,  I need it to work like "append function" for lists. Is there anyway to do so?

Comment: In my opinion, pickle is the most easiest approach then.